# Chart.js 2.9.4: how to hide fillText (animation) while it shows callback label

Tags: chart.js, z-index

Chart.js shows callback label when I move with my mouse. It's ok but it shows text of animation below it. It looks weird. I want hide all animations when it shows some label OR I want untransparent background of callback label. Maybe z-index? But how?

You can see it here: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/ - open it at mobile or little monitor.

I found too many things about transparent but I don't found what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Little solution: not use utf8 emojis but use only text.